# How to get Office 365 E-mail notifications on iPhone, without synching the mailbox?

Tags: mail.app, data-synchronization, notifications, office-365

I need to receive notifications on my iPhone whenever I receive a new work E-mail, but since I receive large quantities of E-mails using many GBs, don't want to actually have my E-mails load up and sync on the phone. Is it possible to setup the mail application to only notify me when I get a new E-mail in Office 365, but to not actually download and display the E-mails in the mail app?

Comment: I would install outlook app and validate how much space actually transfers. I see it downloading headers only on my device and a short window like 30 days back initially. This “ask” may be trying to avoid a problem that does not exist.

Comment: I use Outlook for work on my iPhone and while I don't see any preferences *specifically* focused on email size, I do believe @bmike is correct. Outlook will not download big emails. It gives you an option to load images/attachments on larger emails. But I do not believe there is an email client for iOS that doesn't actually fetch email, only notifications of email, sender, subject, etc. You may be out of luck.